# ClasspathXmlApplicationContext with parent of the current ApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, spring-3

Due to another library's requirements, I must define an `ApplicationContext` in my main `ApplicationContext` with a name of `default.context`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans>
    <bean name="default.context" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>../other-file.xml
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean class="MyNiceDependency"/>
</beans>
```

How can I make `MyNiceDependency` available to the `default.context` context? I'm assuming I need to use the `parent` property of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` but how do I inject the current context to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should get the job done:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class ThisApplicationContextFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<ApplicationContext>,
        ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return this.applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationContext getObject() throws Exception {
        return getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ApplicationContext.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Perhaps there's something better or, better yet, included with Spring?